# Pass array of objects from route to route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js and Express.js and I tried to pass an array of objects from route to other route.
I tried to pass through QueryString, but the `typeof` says that it is an object and it doesn't work properly.
I should either pass it to `/contacts` in another way somehow, or convert the result of the QueryString to an array of object and use it.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
app.get('/names', function(req, res) {
    var arr = new Array();
    arr.push({name: 'John'});
    arr.push({name: 'Dani'});

res.redirect('/contacts?arr=' + arr);
})

app.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
    var arr = req.query.arr;
    console.log(arr[0].name);
})
```

Hope you can help, 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `app.locals`.
Basically, it allows you to store some variables for the lifetime of the application.
For routes, there will be `req.app.locals`.

So how to use it then?

```
app.get('/names', function(req, res) {
    var arr = new Array();
    arr.push({name: 'John'});
    arr.push({name: 'Dani'});

    req.app.locals.nameOfYourArr = arr;
    res.redirect('/contacts');
})

app.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
    var arr = req.app.local.nameOfYourArr;
    console.log(arr[0].name);
})
```

(More info can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals))

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.stringify.

```
app.get('/names', function(req, res) {
  var arr = new Array();
  arr.push({name: 'John'});
  arr.push({name: 'Dani'});

  res.redirect('/contacts?arr=' + JSON.stringify(arr));
})

app.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
  var arr = req.query.arr;
  console.log(JSON.parse(arr));
})
```

Comment: Can you mark it as answerd, if it solved the problem for you.
Would be helpful for anyone else who stumbles upon.

Comment: it doens't work, it gives an error; ' Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1', console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) gives this: [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Dani"}]

Comment: Where does it give the error ??
Upon JSON.stringify or upon parse

Comment: This results in the error: "[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", using the exact code you posted.  Just don't want anyone to have to think this will work, because it won't (I wish it did, though).  Just trying to help.

Comment: @Netside This has nothing to do with headers. The error you have posted would occur if you are trying to read/write to error after responding to the client.

Comment: @Shivam I stand corrected, you are right.  Your code does work.  Just checked it by itself (was using it inside of code I had written before).  Sorry.  Would just delete my previous comment, but then yours would still be there and people might wonder.  Upvoted your comment and answer, either way.  Might be better for newbies in the future, anyway :)