# access to values of fields collection in nodejs and express js

Tags: node.js, express

i want to send just the Name of the product to "pos page" not all fields, 
   products fields :

```
[ { _id: 5e77681899b2f43faca5b432,
              Code: 545454332452,
              Qtt: 120,
              Name: 'adidas',
              Price: 9800,
              Categorie: 'basckets',
              avatar: 'avatar-1584883890430.png',
              __v: 0 } ]
```

The routes is:

```
router.post('/searchProduct', function(req, res) {

    var query = { Code: req.body.searchInput };
    EventProduct.find(query ,function(err, products) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log( products )   //display all fields 
        console.log( products.Name )   // display   "undefined" 

        req.app.locals.nameOfYourArr = productsName;     
        res.redirect('/pos');


      } )
});

//pos route

router.get('/pos', function(req, res) {
    var arr = req.app.locals.nameOfYourArr;
    console.log(arr);     // i need to display   "Name: 'adidas'"  

});
```

for passing parameters from route to route i use this 
links: [Pass array of objects from route to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745133/pass-array-of-objects-from-route-to-route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query can return more than one result, it returns an `Array` so if you consider the first result is the right one, select it before trying to access the field: `products[0].Name`.

Also if you need to retrieve it after a redirection, you have to pass it into the URL:

```
res.redirect(`/pos?name=${products[0].Name}`);
```

Then in the `/pos` endpoint:

```
router.get('/pos', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.name);     // i need to display   "Name: 'adidas'"  
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response but for displaying the name i use ` res.redirect("/pos?name= " +products[0].Name) ` , the previous code displayed  ${products[0].Name} not a value of the product

Comment: did you use backticks like I did? ` is different than '

Comment: I did not notice these details, yes your code works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @jakihart you can pass several arguments in the URL, it can also be kept in a session on server-side, it all depends on what you want to do